# Tracking specific Bundles in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi

I'm new using OSGi, I have a doubt about tracking Bundles. I'm using BundleTracker because I want specific bundles, and I want to know which bundle I am using by their IDs. Some Bundles (3) implement the same interface. I want to track just those bundles that implement that interface. How can I do this?

Comment: I would really like to know why you want to do this. In OSGi depending on bundles rather than packages is a code-smell, so you should try to avoid it. Can you explain why you think you need this?

Comment: Im new in OSGi, sorry if I said something that is wrong, I just want to choose a specific service among many bundles that implements the same interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select a specific service you can use service properties for that. This is completely agnostic of bundles. What that means is that you register your service-implementations with specific properties (this is what the `Dictionary`-argument in [`BundleContext.registerService`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#registerService%28java.lang.Class,%20S,%20java.util.Dictionary%29) is for).

Then you can use [`BundleContext.getServiceReferences`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReferences%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) and specify a filter-expression (the syntax is described [here](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Filter.html)) that only selects the service with the correct property. You could set this up so that you always get an array or collection with at most one element.

This all becomes much easier if you use [declarative services](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services), because then you can just specify the property and the filter in the service-descriptor of the providing and consuming component respectively. You can also make one or both ends of it configurable via the [configuration admin](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.html) (properties in the configuration of a service-component are propagated as properties of the exposed services or consumed references). I would really suggest you check out declarative services before starting any serious work in OSGi.

Note that you should be careful to not implement a hard-coded wiring this way, because that would kill modularity.

Comment: Can I filter the implemenetations with ServiceTracker, and then, from these tracked bundles I choose the right one?

Comment: Yes, `ServiceTracker` provides a [constructor that accepts a `Filter`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html#ServiceTracker%28org.osgi.framework.BundleContext,%20org.osgi.framework.Filter,%20org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTrackerCustomizer%29).